# How did Waver appear in Iskandar's reality marble?

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-zero

In the final episode of Ufotable's adaptation of Fate/Stay Night, we were shown a glimpse of what Waver looks like years after the events of Fate/Zero:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Qp641sN.jpg]

In Fate/Zero, we are shown that Iskandar's reality marble contains all of his comrades from the past. One of the soldiers who appeared in his army looks very similar to Waver:

[image: Waver-like person in Iskandar's reality marble]

So is that really Waver? If so, how did he appear in Iskandar's reality marble?

Comment: Who said servants could only be summoned from the past?

Comment: I don't believe it is Waver because everyone in the Reality Marble people Iskander knew? remember that Servants summoned to the Holy Grail Wars are copies of the originals as such Iskander wouldnt know Waver. i would more suspect its an ancestor of Waver's which would add to how well Waver and Iskander are together and how Waver can continue to summon him in the all the Holy Grail Wars they participated in  during Fate/Apocrypha. also give how he doesn't seem to be wearing armor he could be a Magus and thus be from Waver's Grandfather's side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [type moon wiki](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Ionioi_Hetairoi), Iskandar's reality marble is created with help from people who "shared his dreams and pledged allegiance to him after many victories and defeats"

Thus, in essence, Iskandar's reality marble is created by his followers, which Waver is, essentially, by the end of Fate/Zero.

Therefore, Waver is included among the rest of Iskandar's followers inside the Ionoi Hetairoi. However, you might ask how it's possible for older Waver to be here already. Servants and their magic are noted to exist outside of time, so as with Shirou and Archer, it's not unreasonable for the two to exist in the same time through the power of Rider's noble phantasm.

EDIT - Several other things of note, as suggested by :
First, consider Waver's oath to Rider. On the last day of the 4th Grail War, Waver uses all of his command seals on Rider, effectively stepping down as Rider's master. However, Rider insists that Waver ride into battle with him *as a friend*. Furthermore, after Rider's death, Waver promises to live in order to tell the story of "his king." All this lends support to the idea that Waver is a follower of Iskandar, just like everyone else inside Rider's Noble Phantasm. [source](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Waver_Velvet#Fate.2FZero).

To elaborate on how Servants exist outside of time, according to [this](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Heroic_Spirit) heroic spirits are "freed from the constraints of time itself and removed from the ring of reincarnation, moved to the Throne of Heroes" which exists "outside of both the world and the time axis"

Answer (score 5):

That's not Waver. He may look similar but he is explicitly named as Eumenes in the Case Files Materials book.

[image: from case file materials]

Another one of Iskandar's soldiers is Ptolemy.

[image: Ibid]

Note that the designs discepencies from the *Zero* anime. The above designs are exclusively made for the *Case Files* anime.

[image: Comparison]